# Does OkHTTP or Apache HTTP Client 5 support running AIX?

Tags: java, okhttp, aix, http2, apache-httpclient-5.x

Just noticed that netty-tcnative-boringssl doesn't support AIX(tried on AIX and confirmed by netty-tcnative's dev). Which got my ass burning and eager to find the alternative solution for HTTP2 with native openssl lib as sooner as possible.

Since I need to run it on Java8 which doesn't have HTTP2, so they must have native support of it. Does anyone know Apache HTTP Client 5 or OkHTTP have native openssl(boringSSL) builtin, or addon lib that could make them running without using JDK's SSL provider?

Comment: Recent versions of Java 8’s SSL provide include ALPN support, which is the thing you need for HTTP/2. Will that work?

Comment: @JesseWilson APNS. Gotta make a new push APP to replace the old socket type of push before end of month.